# How to combine array of hashes into one array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to combine an array of hashes like this:

```rb
[{:locale=>:"en-US", :key=>:key1}, 
 {:locale=>:"en-US", :key=>:key2}, 
 {:locale=>:da,      :key=>:key1}]
```

Into one array like this:

```rb
['locale', 'en-US', 'key', 'key1', 
 'locale', 'en-US', 'key', 'key2', 
 'locale', 'da',    'key', 'key1']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please make an attempt before asking for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input

```
a=[{:locale=>:"en-US", :key=>:key1}, {:locale=>:"en-US", :key=>:key2}, {:locale=>:da, :key=>:key1}]
```

Code

```
result=a.map do |h|
  h.map do|k,v|
    [k,v]
  end
end.flatten
p result
```

Or

```
p a.flat_map(&:to_a).flatten
```

Output

```
[:locale, :"en-US", :key, :key1, :locale, :"en-US", :key, :key2, :locale, :da, :key, :key1]
```

Comment: Another option `a.flat_map(&:flatten)`

Comment: @rajagopalan Just `map` (no `flat_map`) is fine too.

Comment: Note that the OP wishes to construct an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Or, even quicker and easier:

```
array = [{:locale=>:"en-US", :key=>:key1}, {:locale=>:"en-US", :key=>:key2}, {:locale=>:da, :key=>:key1}]
array.map { |hash| [hash.keys, hash.values] }.flatten
```